# How to take screenshot of a div and upload image to database using JavaScript, Ajax and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an main image, then a secondary image that I lay over the top of the main image.  I then want to take a picture of the DIV and save the image to an email folder.
When I execute page I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined: capture3.php:23:5.  Which references the error in line 23.  ***$('#takeshot').on('click', function() {***
I am not so good with Javascript and Ajax.  But I know this is not getting to the PHP page.  Thanks in advance for any help.

capture3.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> How to take screenshot of a div and upload image to databast using JavaScript?</title>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.5/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="image">

<img src="images/10137-Charcoal-2-91MCharcoalModelBack-1200W.jpg" />
<img src="knife_river.png" style="margin-top:-400px;margin-left:-200px" />
<br><br>
<button id="takeshot" onclick="takeshot();">
Take Screenshot and save to email folder
</button>
<br><br>

</div>

<h1>Screenshot:</h1>

<div id="output"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#takeshot').on('click', function() {
var file_data = $('#output').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();  // Create a FormData object
form_data.append('file', file_data);  // Append all element in FormData  object
$.ajax({
url         : 'capture_image_script.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
cache       : false,
contentType : false,
processData : false,
data        : form_data,                         
type        : 'post',
success     : function(output){
alert(output);              // display response from the PHP script, if any
}
});
$('#output').val('');                     /* Clear the input type file */
});    
// Define the function 
// to screenshot the div
function takeshot() {
let div = document.getElementById('image');
// Use the html2canvas
// function to take a screenshot
// and append it
// to the output div
html2canvas(div).then(
function (canvas) {
document
.getElementById('output')
.appendChild(canvas);
})
}

</script>
</html>
```

capture_image_script.php

```
<?php

if ( $_FILES['file']['error'] > 0 ){
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/email/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
        echo "File Uploaded Successfully";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$(...)` is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) syntax, but you don't seem to be loading it (it's an external library that you need to include, just like you're including `html2canvas`)

Comment: Thank your for responce M. Ericson.  Dummy me, I know better than that, so I added      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> to my header and then the error changes to  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prop(...) is undefined.  This is around line 24, the code - var file_data = $('#output').prop('files')[0];  Once again I am stuck due to my limited coding knowlege in javascript and ajax, but I'm trying.  Please assist further :)

Comment: `$('#output')` is selecting your div with the id `output`. Then you're trying to fetch an undefined property named `files` on that (`.prop('files')`) which makes no sense. And then you use that (undefined) property as if it were an array `[0]`. What makes even less sense is that you store this in `file_data`, a variable you're trying to redeclare (will also throw an error) and overwrite in the very next line.

Comment: Tbh, it looks like you've just found different code snippets online and put them together without actually knowing what they do or how they work. I would sincerely recommend you to take a step back, break your code down into smaller pieces, implement them one by one and don't move on to the next before you, not only gotten it to work, but also actually understand how.